# How to get previous quarter details in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE j_work_status (
    Work_req_id int(8) NOT NULL,
    Work_status varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Date_Requested timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    date_assigned timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    Date_completed timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    Resource varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    Completed_by varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Work_req_id),
    CONSTRAINT j_work_status_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (Work_req_id)
        REFERENCES j_work_requests (Work_Req_ID)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE j_survey_response (
    Work_req_id int(8) NOT NULL,
    Satisfaction_score tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
    Response_score tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
    Responder_score tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
    Service_score tinyint(2) DEFAULT '0',
    Score_avg decimal(3 , 2 ) DEFAULT '0.00',
    Satisfaction_notes varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Work_req_id),
    CONSTRAINT j_survey_response_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (Work_req_id)
        REFERENCES j_work_requests (Work_Req_ID)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Both tables have almost 20K records.
If year and quarter of year are given I need to display count of score_avg for previous 3 quarter whose work_status is complete.

For example, if year = 2016 and quarter =1, I need to display for Q1-2016, Q4-2015, Q3-2015, Q2-2015 details.

Till now I have query to display all details grouped by year and quarter.

```
select 
    work_status,
    count(score_avg) survey_completed,
    quarter(date_completed) Quarter,
    year(date_completed) Year
from
    j_work_status
        join
    j_survey_response ON j_survey_response.work_req_id = j_work_status.work_req_id
where
    work_status = 'complete' and year(date_completed)
group by Quarter , Year
```

Please anyone help me in finding previous 3 quarter details

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add